# Redirect output from CLIPS to .Net (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, clips

I'm trying to integrate CLIPS and C# application.I'm a newbie at CLIPS so I can't understand how to get expression from "printout t" construction.
I've load `.clp` file, assert facts, run it, but now I want to redirect output to my application in C#.
Sorry for dumb question but I will be grateful if you will show me example or links to samples.

For example,

```
(deftemplate 1Data (slot name)(slot age))
(defrule 1Data (1Data (name Tim)(age ?age))=>
  (printout t crlf "Tim is " ?age " years old" crlf))
```

I need to get and use "Tim is " ?age " years old" expression in .Net project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the router system defined in Section 7 of the Advanced Programming Guide, http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/apg.pdf. For use in C#, you will probably need to wrap the C code with a C# class for use in C#. There's a project at http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsnet/ that contains code that may be useful in doing this. I couldn't get the projects to compile, but the source code can give you some ideas on how to get started.

Comment: @ Gary Riley, sure, I've read about I/O system in CLIPS both in Basic and Advanced Guides. Also I tried to use CLIPSNet.dll but I couldn't find any DLL documentation therefore I had to use ExpertSystem.dll. Later I will try remake my project using CLIPSNet.dll. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've created some examples which demonstrate how to integrate a .NET Common Language Runtime wrapper around the native CLIPS code with Windows Forms and Windows Presentation Foundation projects. Information is available here: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/CLIPSNETBeta.html

Comment: The examples are now just included with the windows projects, clips_windows_projects_640.zip, with CLIPS: https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.40/.